# Check for null values in API response

Tags: java, api, null

I have an api, when it is the best rated movie returns values like

```
[
 {
  "movieId":"o1",
  "movie name":"Dory",
  "rating":"Best"
 }
]
```

If not it returns

```
[
 {
  "movieId":null,
  "movie name":null,
  "rating":null
 }
]
```

I used a rest template that calls the api using the execute method

```
public List<Movies> getRatingViaApi(String id){
    
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //String resourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/movies";
    
        
        RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.writeValue(request.getBody(), 
                        id);

                request.getHeaders()
                 .setAccept(Arrays.asList(
                         MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, 
                         MediaType.ALL));
                };

        
        ResponseExtractor<List<Movies>> responseExtractor = response -> 
ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper ();

                return mapper.readValue(response.getBody(),new TypeReference<List<Movies>>(){});
             };

        restTemplate.execute(resourceUrl, 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            requestCallback, 
            responseExtractor );    
}
```

How can I check if the Api response gives a null value or not
Or if it is the best movie or not

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like that?

```java
@Data
public class Movies {

    private static final String THE_BEST_RATING = "Best";

    private String movieId;
    private String movieName;
    private String rating;

    public boolean isPresent() {
        return ObjectUtils.allNull(movieId, movieName, rating);
    }

    public boolean isTheBest() {
        return Objects.equals(THE_BEST_RATING, rating);
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        // download list

        List<Movies> existingMovies = moviesList.stream() // list of "non null objects"
                                                .filter(Movies::isPresent)
                                                .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));

        existingMovies.stream()
                      .filter(Movies::isTheBest)
                      .forEach(movie -> System.out.println("Movie: " + movie + " is the best")); //printing the bests movies
    }
```

Comment: is there an alternative to ObjectUtil.allNull?

Comment: return movieId == null && movieName  == null && rating == null

or static import java.util.Objects.isNull

return isNull(movieId) && isNull(movieName) && isNull(rating)

will give same result. Also you could try to use reflaction and check all fields in a loop to search non null values. I see no other way to handle "empty" list from this API.